# How to use substitute function with query function in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I am trying to use substitute function inside a query function but not able to find the correct syntax to do that. My use case is as follows.

I have two columns **Name** and **Salary**. Values in these columns have **comas** ',' in them. I want to import these two columns to a new spreadsheet but replace comas in "**Salary**" column with empty string and retain comas in "**Name**" column. I also want to apply value function to "**Salary**" column after removing comas to do number formatting.

I tried with the following code but it is replacing comas in both the columns. I want a code which can apply the substitute function only to a subset of columns.

**Code**:

```
=arrayformula(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(Address,"Sheet1!A2:B5"),"Select *"),",",""))
```

**Result**:

Converted v/s Expected Result[image]

**Note** :

I have almost 10 columns to import and comas should be removed from 3 of them.

Comment: What is the purpose of the query if it selects all (`"Select *"`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your suggestions, I was able to achieve the objective by treating columns separately. Below is the code.

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(Address,"Sheet1!A3:A5"),arrayformula(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTRANGE(Address,"Sheet1!B3:B5"),",","")))},"Select * where Col2 is not null")
```

Basically, two IMPORTRANGE functions side by side for each column.

The same query on the actual data with 10 columns will look like this.

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(Address,"Sheet1!A3:C"),arrayformula(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTRANGE(Address,"Sheet1!D3:H"),",",""))),IMPORTRANGE(Address,"Sheet1!I3:J")},"Select * where Col2 is not null")
```

I used 3 IMPORTRANGE functions so that I can format the columns D to H by removing comas and changing them to number.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use 2 formulas and more space in your sheets.

Formula #1: get the data and replace commas:

`=arrayformula(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTRANGE(Address,"Sheet1!A2:B5"),",",""))`

Formula #2: to convert text into numbers:

`=arrayformula (range_of_text_to_convert * 1)`

Notes:

- using 2 formulas will need extra space, but will speed up formulas (`importrange` is slow)
- the second formula uses math operation (`*1`) which is the same as `value` formula.

Comment: Working perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I treats the columns separately.

```
=arrayformula(QUERY({Sheet1!A2:A5,SUBSTITUTE(Sheet1!B2:B5,",","")},"Select *"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ed Nelson, I was able to figure out this:

```
=arrayformula(QUERY({'Accepted Connections'!A:R,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE('Accepted Connections'!A:R,"AIF®",""),"APA",""),"APMA®",""),"ASA",""),"C(k)P®",""),"C(k)PS",""),"CAIA",""),"CBA",""),"CBI",""),"CCIM",""),"","")},"Select *"))
```

That removed all the text I didn't need in specific columns.